# Convert .live() to .on()

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

How do I go about combining this old jQuery code into the v1.7 `.on()`?

v1.3 `.live()`:

```
    $('#results tbody tr').live({
    mouseenter:
       function () { $(this).find('.popup').show(); },
    mouseleave:
       function () { $(this).find('.popup').hide(); }
    });
```

v1.7 `.on()`:

```
$('#results tbody').on('mouseenter', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).find('.popup').show();
});
$('#results tbody').on('mouseleave', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).find('.popup').hide();
});
```

I want to pass both event handlers to one `.on()` call, but keep the brilliant event delegation `.on()` allows me to do.

Comment: Whats' wrong with your second example? You could chain both `on()` calls off one selector, but other than that I see no issues.

Comment: No, there's no issues, I just want to pass both event handlers in one object, like I do in the first example. Thanks for the super quick reply, by the way.

Comment: TJ. answers the actual question, but Rory is right that in a case like this you could just use a single, dyanmic handler method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass an event-map as the first parameter:

```
$('#results tbody').on({
    'mouseenter' : function () {
        $(this).find('.popup').show();
     },
    'mouseleave' : function () {
        $(this).find('.popup').hide();
    }
}, 'tr');
```

[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> **.on( events-map [, selector] [, data] )**,
>   **events-map** A map in which the string keys represent one or more space-separated event types and
>   optional namespaces, and the values represent a handler function to be
>   called for the event(s).

Answer (score 3):

> I just want to pass both event handlers in one object, like I do in the first example.

In this case you could attach the two events together, then differentiate them in the handler itself, like this:

```
$('#results tbody').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'tr', function (e) {
    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
        $(this).find('.popup').show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('.popup').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is nice! I think it would come in handy in cases where you are binding many event handlers on the same element - and you could use a select switch to capture everything.

Answer (score 1):

The formats used are specified in the documentation for [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$(document).on({...events...}, selector, data);
```

-or-

```
$(document).on(event, selector, data, callback);
```

The code for the `live` function in 1.7+ is now just a pass-through function:

```
live: function( types, data, fn ) {
    jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Taking your first example and changing `live` to `on` should be all that you need

```
 $('#results tbody tr').on({
mouseenter:
   function () { $(this).find('.popup').show(); },
mouseleave:
   function () { $(this).find('.popup').hide(); }
})
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/on/#example-6

Comment: But then you'll be missing the event delegation. Look at TJ's answer :)