# jQuery: converting .live to .on/.off

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery 1.7 - Turning live() into on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on)

I have this code:

```
<script>
        jQuery('#ultimecomunicazioni')
    .live("mouseenter", function() {
        jQuery(this).append('<span id="ultimecomunicazioni_appear" style="font-weight:normal;margin-left:5px">(<a style="color:grey" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>comunicazioni/">tutte</a>)</span>');
    })
    .live("mouseleave", function() {
        jQuery(this).children('#ultimecomunicazioni_appear').remove();
    });
</script>
```

I'd like to change the two .live to .on and combine the 2 handlers in one. I tried to use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636932/jquery-convert-live-to-on) by TJ but I get confused from the 'tr' at the end.. it should be something like this but I'm not sure:

```
<script>
jQuery('#ultimecomunicazioni').on({
    'mouseenter' : function () {
        jQuery(this).append('<span id="ultimecomunicazioni_appear" style="font-weight:normal;margin-left:5px">(<a style="color:grey" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>comunicazioni/">tutte</a>)</span>');
     },
    'mouseleave' : function () {
        jQuery(this).children('#ultimecomunicazioni_appear').remove();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Have you tried it?

Comment: I am sorry.. What is the question really?

Comment: @JanDvorak yep, doesn't work.. :P

Comment: use `appendTo` it's safer (works the other way round) & `find` instead of `children` (it's faster). you can delegate your events from body or a main container, it's also faster & eats up very less memory + it'll then work on dynamically appended element as well

Comment: @mikakun interesting! can you post an example? :)

Comment: @mikakun why do you think `appendTo` is faster?

Comment: @JanDvorak, not faster, safer (reread & i did not edit!) - i've had lots of trouble with ie using append few years back so turned my back on it

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, that's the duplicate for the question, but his actual issue is more like [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", "#ultimecomunicazioni" , function(e) {
    if(e.type === 'mouseenter'){
        $(this).append('<span id="ultimecomunicazioni_appear" style="font-weight:normal;margin-left:5px">(<a style="color:grey" href="comunicazioni/">tutte</a>)</span>');
    } else {
        $('#ultimecomunicazioni_appear').remove();
    }
});
```

**Note**: I have removed the little `php echo` code since that does not work with javascript (server vs client side languages)

Comment: Thanks! Works! :) Is this better than http://jsfiddle.net/5xS6W/1/ ?

Comment: Depends on your needs. They are essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the docs for [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and the part on [delegated events for `.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), it's explained there pretty good.

> Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is
>   straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all
>   three event attachment methods:
>
> `$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+`
>
> `$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+`
>
> `$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+`

However, I can't see why you ever would need delegated functionality on one element with a certain id. It seems likely that you just experience [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572).

Comment: Can you quote the relevant part in case the link rots?

Comment: @Jan: Yeah, since it's an answer I probably should do that. Originally it was intended as a RTFM-comment…

Comment: I'm reading the docs and trying to make it working with $(document).on();

Comment: @Bergi This should be ok, right..? :)
http://jsfiddle.net/5xS6W/1/

Comment: No, not really. Read http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572 and have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/5xS6W/2/

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this :

```
<script>
jQuery('#ultimecomunicazioni').parent().on({
    'mouseenter' : function () {
        jQuery(this).append('<span id="ultimecomunicazioni_appear" style="font-weight:normal;margin-left:5px">(<a style="color:grey" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>comunicazioni/">tutte</a>)</span>');
     },
    'mouseleave' : function () {
        jQuery(this).children('#ultimecomunicazioni_appear').remove();
    }
},
'#ultimecomunicazioni'
);
</script>
```

Comment: Delegating to itself? What for?

Comment: Is that all you've changed is that you've added the second parameter, attempting delegation to itself?

Comment: look again , I forget .parent

Comment: I still see no reason this should work any better than the original except in rare cases (which do exist).

Comment: You mean my code doesn't work.

Comment: Unless the asker removes and readds the element with said ID or there are two elements with the same ID (former of which gets removed), your code doesn't help anything.

Comment: I'll still keep it unvoted in the rare case it helps somebody who removes and readds some element. Delegating to `document` would still probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting about the fact, that jQuerys original `.live()` method was in that way special, that it **always** bound the *event listener* to the `document.body`. That was big critique point also, because most of the time it was unnecessary to place the handler so far away at the top of the document.

`.delegate()` was more like `.on()` in its current form, but they changed the order of arguments from

```
method(<element>, <event>, <callback>)
```

into

```
method(<event>, <element>, >callback>)
```

I'm uncertain if that affects your original code, but if it requires for some reason that the event handler is on `document.body` level instead the one you called `.on()` for, it might cause some trouble.

Comment: Uhm.. my just made an element appear when I passed the mouse on another element. you can see it live here http://goo.gl/8Nxnu (search for "Ultime circolari", when you hover it an element appears at its right).

Answer (score 0):

As i saw your code this seems that you are having issues with the `php` part in the appending content:

```
jQuery('#ultimecomunicazioni').on({
'mouseover': function () {
    jQuery(this).append('<span id="ultimecomunicazioni_appear" style="font-weight:normal;margin-left:5px">(<a style="color:grey" 
href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( / ) ); ?>comunicazioni/">tutte</a>)</span>');
},    //---------------------------^-^-----------------------here
    'mouseleave': function () {
    jQuery(this).children('#ultimecomunicazioni_appear').remove();
}
});
```

i just removed the quotes here and your code worked : http://jsfiddle.net/CrXZr/

Comment: Uhm.. really weird! Anyway in the fiddle everytime I pass the mouse on the "(tutte)" another element appears

Comment: yes because div is not fixed with width and height and you can use `event.stopPropagation()` on span's mouse over.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document.body).on({
    'mouseenter' : function () {
        $('<span id="ultimecomunicazioni_appear"/>').appendTo($(this));
 },
    'mouseleave' : function () {
       $(this).find('#ultimecomunicazioni_appear').remove();
 }, '#ultimecomunicazioni'
```

});

Comment: Uhm.. see your example live here http://goo.gl/8Nxnu (search for "Ultime comunicazioni", at the right should appear an element, like for "Ultime circolari", the widget just below, but nothing happens..)

Comment: if nothing happens, comes from css or html (typing error, no definition missing...)